PAM JBPM query by correlation key does not work
I am enhancing this sample https://www.mastertheboss.com/bpm/jbpm6/jbpm-6-web-application-example/. I have a requirement to get deployment id and the process id of a process instances that completed in the history. So that I can rerun the workflow using a historical deployment id and a process id.
I tried to implement that by providing an identifier when starting the process and later query it using the same identifier. For that I created a CorrelationKey  using an id and included that as an argument to startProcess(). But, when I try to query using the same correlationKey, it does not provide any results.
How I start process,
@Bean
    public CorrelationKeyFactory correlationKeyFactory(){
        return new JPACorrelationKeyFactory();
    }
    private CorrelationKey generateCorrelationKey(String key) {
        return factory.newCorrelationKey(key);
    }



CorrelationKey correlationKey = generateCorrelationKey("1234);
Long processInstanceId = processService.startProcess("business-application-kjar-1_0-SNAPSHOT", "com.mastertheboss.LicenseDemo", correlationKey, vars);

How I query,
    CorrelationKey correlationKey = generateCorrelationKey("1234");
    ProcessInstanceDesc processInstanceById = runtimeDataService.getProcessInstanceByCorrelationKey(correlationKey); 

However, if I query using process instance id, it produces results
runtimeDataService.getProcessInstanceById(processId)  

